# Unable to write file. Volume mounted as root

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

I am spinning up a Pod (comes up with Non Root user) that needs to write data to a volume. The volume comes from a PVC.

The pod definition is simple

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: task-pv-pod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: task-pv-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
       claimName: test-pvc
  containers:
    - name: task-pv-container
      image: jnlp/jenkins-slave:latest
      command: ["/bin/bash"]
      args: ["-c", "sleep 500"]
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: "http-server"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
          name: task-pv-storage
```

When I `exec` into the Pod and try to write into `/usr/share/nginx/html`

I get

```
jenkins@task-pv-pod:/usr/share/nginx/html$ touch test
touch: cannot touch ‘test’: Permission denied
```

Looking at the permissions of the directory

```
jenkins@task-pv-pod:~$ ls -ld /usr/share/nginx/html
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar 29 15:52 /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Its clear that ONLY root user can write to `/usr/share/nginx/html` but thats not what I want.

Is there a way to change the permissions for mounted volumes ?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using an **initContainer** to mount your volume and change permissions. The initContainer will be run before the main container(s) start up. The usual pattern for this usage is to have a busybox image (~22 MB) to mount the volume and run a chown or chmod on the directory. When your pod's primary container runs, the volume(s) will have the correct ownership/access privileges.

Alternatively, you can consider using the initContainer to inject the proper files as shown in [this example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-initialization/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

A security context defines privilege and access control settings for a Pod or Container.          Just try [securityContext](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context):

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: task-pv-pod
spec:
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: $jenkins_uid
  volumes:
    - name: task-pv-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
       claimName: test-pvc
...
```

Comment: Just use the same `fsGroup` for the `securityContext` under `spec` and the `securityContext` under your container. Then, you should be able to have the write access.